# Applying CSS3 to pseudo-class first-child

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have markup that goes something like this

```
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='container'>
Body Container content
</div>

<div class='container'>
Footer Container content
</div>
</div>
```

I want to display a header containing, amongst other things, a logo above the first, body, container.  This I accomplished by defining

```
.container::before
{
 background-image(url(path/to/image.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 content:'';
}
```

The above works.  The problem is that the logo ends up not onlyu above the body content but also above the footer content which is not quite the desired result.  I have played around with various combinations of

```
.container::before:nth-of-child(1)
{

}

.container:nth-of-child(1)::before
{

}
```

but I haven't quite found the right syntax to target the `::before` pseudo element for the first `.container` instance.  I hope that someone here will be able to tell me how it should be done.

If the worst comes to the worst I can do it with a spot of jQuery but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: How about adding a new class to the first body container element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I'll add another answer because it doesn't appear that anyone has solved all of your issues.

First, there is a typo in your css: `background-image(url(path/to/image.jpg)` is missing the closing paren.

To do what you want, however, there is a simple css selector :).  In your example, you try `nth-to-child()`, but the correct syntax for what you want is `nth-child()`.  Look below for two options, with a working demo.

```css
.container:first-child:before
{
  display: block;
  content: "Before Element";
  /* other styling that you choose*/
}

/* the following selector will also work 
.container:nth-child(1):before
{
  display: block;
  content: "Before Element";
}
*/
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='container'>
    Body Container content
  </div>

  <div class='container'>
    Footer Container content
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the `display: block;` part is so that the before content appears on it's own line, since `:before` elements by default are `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: I am accepting your answer since it provides a way to do what I wanted without injecting any additional markup.

Answer (score 3):

Would you consider using `<main>` [W3 4.4.14 The main element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) and `<footer>` [4.4.9 The footer element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-footer-element.html) per HTML5 elements with class of `.container` on each? That way you can reference/target those elements without psuedo elements

```
main::before
{
 background-image(url(path/to/image.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 content:'';
}
```

This way the header/logo you are looking for would only appear above the first container only. Then if you need to apply pseudo elements to `<footer>` you could do something like:

```
footer::before
{
 background-image(url(path/to/image.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 content:'';
}
```

Comment: I am in the process of hacking an inherited Wordpress theme.  I hesitate to start putting in new page elements but I tried what you suggested - wrapping the first container in a `<div id='main'></div>` element and it appears to be working.  I am leaving this question open for a while longer just in case someone comes up with an alternative. In any case, thanks. I might just accept your answer in the end.

Comment: You could definitely add some classes/id to your HTML elements and keep theme as the div elements. That way you could style those major sections as well accordingly. Let me know if that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that there is a way to making it work with `nth-of-child`, but it will definitely work with `first-child` (if you always need it only in the first element with class `.container`):

```
.container:first-child:before
{
 background-image(url(path/to/image.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 content:'';
}
```

Comment: `nth-child(1)` will work the same as `first-child` in your example

Comment: I believe it will. but the Op is using nth-of-child instead of nth-child.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought here is that there should be an additional class for the header, or use the `<header>` and `<footer>` elements in place of divs. For example:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="container header">
       Header
    </div>
    <div class="container footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.header::before {
    // stuff to make your logo
}
```

However, if for some reason you can't change the html, then the :first-child selector should work for your needs, as others have answered.

Comment: since you're hacking on an inherited wordpress theme, adding a class that's not used elsewhere ("my-header" or something) to the header element should have no side effects, then you can attach your custom css to that class instead of the classes built in to the theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `nth-child()` you need to add it to the parent of the element that you want to select. In this case `.wrap`.

```
.wrap:nth-child(1):before
{
 background-image(url(path/to/image.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 content:'';
}
```